# 2 column with same ID to 1 row

Tags: sql

I have a table with only 2 column which is as follow

```
|ID  | Date       |
===================
|1   | 03/04/2017 |
|1   | 09/07/1997 |
|2   | 04/04/2014 |
```

I want to achieve an end result as follow

```
|ID  | Date 1     |Date 2      |
================================
|1   | 03/04/2017 | 09/07/1997 |
|2   | 04/04/2014 | NULL       |
```

I'm currently reading up on PIVOT function and I'm not sure am I on the right track. Am still new to SQL

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.)?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: `SELECT ID, MIN(Date) AS date_1, MAX(Date) AS date_2 FROM yourTable GROUP BY ID`

Comment: Am using SQL Server, just tried PIVOT function and it gave me only 1 of the date in ID '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot query should work here, with a twist.  For your `ID` 2 data, there is only one row, but in this case you want to report a first date and a `NULL` second date.  We can use a `CASE` expression to handle this case.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(Date) AS date_1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 2 THEN MIN(Date) ELSE NULL END AS date_2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I didn't check the result well;) +1

Comment: @Pரதீப் I was actually going to tell you not to answer the newbie pivot query question, but then I realized there was a twist, so I decided to answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, the result is what I want. But can I ask what if my ID 1 has 3 dates while ID 2 remain with only 1 date

Comment: No, your ID 1 has _two_ dates, while ID 2 has _one_ date.  The result can only have data which appears in the input.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the trouble I'm making. I understand that the solution you gave me have already solved my question. But I'm asking what if in my table ID 1 have 3 dates or more, how do I split them up into columns. I'm currently looking at dynamic pivot and also pivot but I'm getting more confused on it now. Sorry for making so much trouble

Comment: If you have three dates, then you'd need to change the answers given here.  You could look into using `PIVOT`, changing my query, or using some dynamic SQL.  But in any case, you should probably open a new question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Really grateful for your time and answer It helps a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using `min/max` aggregate function

```
select Id,min(Date),
        case when min(Date)<>max(Date) then max(Date) end
From yourtable 
Group by Id
```

If this will not help you with your original data, then alter sample data and expected result